# Eclipse Oomph windows 64 bit installer downloading linux tools

Tags: java, eclipse

I am installing eclipse using the Oomph installer tool.

I am seeing in the logs that linux tools are getting downloaded, which is taking time as well.

I would like to understand the reason. If we are installing Eclipse using Oomph we are not sure of what plugins and jars will be downloaded. How does this work?

> Collecting 1 artifacts from
>   http://download.eclipse.org/linuxtools/updates-docker-nightly/
>
> Downloading org.bouncycastle.bcprov
>
> Fetching org.bouncycastle.bcprov_1.52.0.v20160915-1535.jar from
>   http://download.eclipse.org/linuxtools/updates-docker-nightly/plugins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java lives on dependencies. For instance, bouncycastle is a crypto library. It's used for many things, including securing connections. It's probably a dependency of at least 10 other tools in Eclipse.

Whenever a Java tool in Eclipse declares a dependency, the installer is going to go out to a public repository and fetch that dependency so your program will build properly. That's generally true of installers and build tools beyond Eclipse as well.

Answer (score 1):

Any Eclipse installation based on Oomph uses a "Set Up Model" which is just a declarative description of which Eclipse plugins from which "p2 repositories" (= URLs of site that offer Eclipse plugins) are downloaded.

Are you by any chance seeing this problem when using (my...) https://github.com/vorburger/opendaylight-eclipse-setup ? ;-)  I used to include "http://download.eclipse.org/linuxtools/updates-docker-nightly/, but [have long since removed it again](https://github.com/vorburger/opendaylight-eclipse-setup/commit/0c9045f0ca8ddb6fb15c8722533f20e4fc309175#diff-c6b57d6f928ec9659aedc6d9298e9ce9).